# Mounting only a specific part of sysfs

Tags: linux, mount, chroot, sysfs

I wonder if it is possible to mount only part of sysfs for usage in chroot. Example I would require only /sys/class/gpio and rest is not required.

```
mount -t sysfs sys/some/folder /mnt/temp_sys
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generic way to do this for any kind of file systems is `bind` mount.

This example is using `/tmp`. To do that on `/sys` you may replace `/tmp/sysall` by `/sys`:

```
mkdir /tmp/sysall
mkdir -p /tmp/mychroot/sys/class/gpio

mount -t sysfs sysfs /tmp/sysall/
mount --bind  /tmp/sysall/class/gpio  /tmp/mychroot/sys/class/gpio
umount /tmp/sysall/
```